# How can I show the X and Y axes over this plane?

Tags: object-mode

[image: Plane somehow over the axes]

*Image 1: Plane somehow hiding the axes*

I'm a newbie and I'm following the famous donut tutorials by Andrew Price aka Blender Guru. At part 6, Level 1 he instructs us to create a plane, but in his video the X/Y axes are shown over the plane, while in my re-creation they don't show up at all inside the plane. Why is this?

[image: Andrew's plane and axes]

*Image 2: Andrew's plane and axes*

Comment: It could just have to do with position - it's just a visual thing with the axes. If an object (in this case, the plane) is flush with or "above" (higher on z) the X/Y axis intersection, it will block it and you won't see the lines, if it is below, you will see the axes over the plane. It's been a while since I watched the donut tutorial, but I'm guessing Andrew just moved the plane down a little.

Comment: Ooh, makes sense. I'm gonna move it a little bit, then. Thanks!

Comment: In the Object tab, 'Viewport Display' panel, there's an option to show the object's own (as opposed to the World's) axes, which can be quite useful.